# XML Schema (XSD) - How to specify parent element to contain at least one child element?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I have an XML schema (XSD) that defines an element as mandatory (call it the parent); this parent has, lets say, five child elements, which can all be optional, BUT AT LEAST ONE child element must occur.

How can i specify this in the xsd?

To clarify: The children are different elements and optional.
For example.

```
<Parent>
   <Child1>contents are different to other siblings and arbitrary</Child1>
   <Child2>can be text, a simple element, or another complex element</Child2>
   <Child3>etc.. etc</Child3> 
</Parent>

<xs:complexType name="Parent">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Child1" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Child2" />
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Child3" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Even though every child is optional, the parent needs to have at least one child.

Comment: After reviewing the answers (and lots of Googling), it seems there is no easy construct in xsd to specify this; More trouble than it's worth, i have opted to let the validating software enforce additional rules (such as At Least One child must occur).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is always the direct approach:

```
<xs:complexType name="Parent">
  <xs:choice>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Child1"/>
      <xs:element name="Child2" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="Child3" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Child2"/>
      <xs:element name="Child3" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Child3"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: Direct approach would probably work; but gets too cumbersome for lots of child elements.

Comment: JAXB is generating bad result when you transform it to Java class

Answer (score 3):

Using assertions (I think it is only available in XSD 1.1) it is possible to do the following:

```
<xs:element name="Parent">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Child1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="Child2" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="Child3" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:assert test="count(*)>=1"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 1):

```xml
<xs:complexType name="Parent">
  <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:element name="Child1" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="Child2" />
    <xs:element name="Child3" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Putting the `maxOccurs="unbounded"` to the choice (`minOccurs=1` by default => at least one child)

Answer (score 0):

Use minOccurs, e.g.

```
<xsd:complexType name="Parent">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="5" name="Child" type="q10:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Comment: Not quite what i intended. Please see updated question that hopefully clarifies the intent.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a substitution group which incorporates all your child elements. For this you use the `minOccurs` attribute to specify that at least one element of the group must occur in the document.

Comment: Dont think this will work; substitution group elements must somehow be related or derived from each other; my elements are totally independent as alluded to in my question.