# How to use XSD occurance indicators to denote at least one required

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I'd like to create a element that requires at least 1 child to exist, but may have multiple occurrences of one or more child.

The following examples would all be valid :

```
<Parent>
    <ChildA></ChildA>
    <ChildB></ChildB>
</Parent>

<Parent>
    <ChildB></ChildB>
    <ChildA></ChildA>
</Parent>

<Parent>
    <ChildB></ChildB>
    <ChildA></ChildA>
    <ChildB></ChildB>
    <ChildB></ChildB>
    <ChildB></ChildB>
    <ChildA></ChildA>
</Parent>
```

This would be invalid:

```
<Parent>
</Parent>
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490610/xml-schema-xsd-how-to-specify-parent-element-to-contain-at-least-one-child-e) but it doesn't seem to allow a variable number of occurrences of any particular child.

[all](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_complex_indicators.asp) doesn't seem to allow for more than one occurrence either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XSD,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Parent">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="ChildA"/>
        <xs:element name="ChildB"/>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

will successfully validate XML that has at least one of the listed child elements.  Your valid examples will be considered valid, but not your invalid example.

Comment: It will also allow `<Parent><ChildA/></Parent>` and `<Parent><ChildB/></Parent>`, and the question isn't entirely clear whether those are to be considered valid or not.

Comment: @MichaelKay: OP does say "requires at least 1 child to exist."  Is there another ambiguity that concerns you?

Comment: Only that I thought it would be good for the OP to be aware of this, because the narrative requirement is rather informally stated, and this particular case isn't covered by the examples.